# How to split Bazel file path into external dependency directory and relative path?

Tags: bazel

I'm working on a custom rule in skylark that is trying to use the proto compiler. Due to intricacies of how it works, I need to split a path into a directory for the external dependency and the path part that is relative to that.

Example1:

`File:[/private/var/tmp/_bazel_endobson/c56b77af296477cd0f319aa9d4ce1d19[source]]external/googleapis/google/devtools/build/v1/build_status.proto`

I want the paths:

`/private/var/tmp/_bazel_endobson/c56b77af296477cd0f319aa9d4ce1d19/external/googleapis/
google/devtools/build/v1/build_status.proto`

Example2:

`File:[[/private/var/tmp/_bazel_endobson/c56b77af296477cd0f319aa9d4ce1d19/execroot/bes_example]bazel-out/darwin_x86_64-fastbuild/genfiles]external/com_google_protobuf/google/protobuf/any.proto`

I want the paths:

`/private/var/tmp/_bazel_endobson/c56b77af296477cd0f319aa9d4ce1d19/execroot/bes_example/bazel-out/darwin_x86_64-fastbuild/genfiles/external/com_google_protobuf 
google/protobuf/any.proto`

The issue is that bazel allows accessing the root and root relative parts of the path, but doesn't give insight into if the path has the 'external/' part or not. The protocol buffer compiler needs this because it needs to know the directories that correspond to the root directories from the user's point of view so that it can use relative paths from the source.

Is there a principled way of detecting this other than hackily looking at the path to see if it has 'external' in it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I cannot give you a really great answer here :( Eventually, we'd like to remove the "external" path segment, but it hasn't happened yet. The current rule is that you have it for source artifacts, but you don't have it for generated artifacts.

Thus, what I'd do is exactly what you suggest -- check if the first path segment is "external".